# Accepted answers are not showing up first

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Up until some time ago, I saw accepted answers atop all other answers.

Today, in all stacks that I browse, I'm not seeing accepted answers being placed at the top - unless they get there by some other criteria such as being the most voted, or most active, depending on the filter I am using.

I couldn't find anything about it. Is this behavior new? Or have I changed some setting somewhere by mistake?

Comment: Do you happen to only be looking at posts where the author accepted their own answer?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I am. Turns out the problem was between the keyboard and the chair.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that a coincidence happened... I had looked at four questions, from four different people, in different stacks, and in each case the person who had asked was the same who had given the answer marked as accepted.

When you accept your own anwer it does not go to the top just for being the accepted one.